# Not able to run ipython nbconvert

Tags: ipython

I have downloaded the `ipython` and `ipython-notebook` packages. The documentation of ipython says that I can run nbconvert to convert my notebooks to html/latex/etc. But am not able to run either `nbconvert` or `ipython nbconvert`.

```
 ~ ipython --version
0.13.1.rc2
 ~ ipython nbconvert
[TerminalIPythonApp] File not found: u'nbconvert'
 ~
```

(I don't know if this is the correct site to ask this.)

Comment: You Will need to be a little more precise. Which version of IPython. How do you try to run nbconvert? Do you have an error message? Etc..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that. I edited the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem in *Ubuntu Xenial 16.04*. Error messages led me to three apps which are needed:

- `pygments`
- `pandoc`
- `nodejs`

After installing those three, I was able to convert an `ipython notebook` to HTML format without an error message, using the command line string:

`ipython nbconvert --to html foo.ipynb`

I found a Python2 library file which calls `nodejs`:

`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/nbconvert/filters/markdown.py`

`markdown.py` contains a class named `NodeJSMissing` which throws up a `ConversionException`. But if `nodejs` remains uninstalled, `Nbconvert will try to use Pandoc instead.` In that sense, `nodejs` is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Nbconvert is part of IPython only since 1.0. If it is not yet in Ubuntu repository, you could try to add [Julian Taylor IPython PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jtaylor/+archive/ipython-dev) that should have more rencent version backported on Ubuntu. You will find information on how to add this PPA on your system on the PPA page. Be carefull, the PPA also contain bleeding edge version of IPython builded every night this is usually usable, but might not be what you like. I'm not a PPA/Ubuntu user myself so I cannot go much further into details.

Comment: How should i add that ppa? Could you please give the commands for that?

Comment: I've edited my answer, first response was short from my phone so now I was able to add links.