# IPython subcommands won't work if you alias the "ipython" command

Tags: 14.04, ipython

I've changed the question title to match the actual cause of my problem.

In my 14.04 setup, `ipython`'s subcommands don't work:

```
$ ipython locate
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: u'locate'
```

This is similar to [another problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395525/not-able-to-run-ipython-nbconvert) from earlier releases of Ubuntu and IPython.  I have the "stock" `ipython` with Ubuntu 14.04.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

I have found that calling `ipython2.7 locate`, for example, works, and this is a kind of work-around for now, but it generates a warning:

```
$ ipython2.7 locate
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/frontend.py:30: UserWarning: The top-level `frontend` package has been deprecated. All its subpackages have been moved to the top `IPython` level.
  warn("The top-level `frontend` package has been deprecated. "
/home/whoever/.config/ipython
```

Is there a nice clean way to fix this?

Comment: In my machine all seems to work as expected (but I also get the warning with `ipython2.7`). What about `ipython locate --log-level=DEBUG`?

Comment: Thanks, that effectively solved my problem: It got me to realize that I've set up `alias ipython='/usr/bin/ipython --pylab qt` in my `.bash_profile`.  So my problem is fundamentally "pilot error."  When I use `/usr/bin/ipython locate` I get the expected result.

Comment: Frank please write your solution and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel a little foolish "answering" my own question when it really is a matter of pilot error.  On the other hand, other people might have the same problem I had, forgetting that we've cleverly aliased a common shell command, and then wondering why it no longer works as advertised.  This issue has bitten me several times.

The solution, if your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc files have "alias" commands in them and they don't work as expected, is to try calling the program by its explicit path.  In my case,

```
ipython somecommand somescript.py
```

triggers the shell's alias expansion, but

```
/usr/bin/ipython somecommand somescript.py
```

Does not.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid shell expations of the alias in bash, you may call it using either

```
\ipython whatever
```

or

```
"ipython" whatever
```

Thanks for your localization of the problem (i mean aliases).